# Passing Sinatra models and validation

Tags: ruby, validation, sinatra

As mentioned on another similar thread I started recently, I am porting an ASP MVC application to Sinatra, partly for learning, partly for production purposes.

Currently my ASP MVC application has no views, it just exposes models as Xml/Json etc and accepts them in the same way. So in the scenario of someone sending a model to the server, it would auto bind the object, perform validation then return validation errors if there are any, if not carry on with the relevant actions.

Now in Sinatra it is a bit more barebones that ASP MVC which is a great thing as I have more choice on how to do these parts, however I dont have a clue what gems/libraries functionality is available for doing this.

My ideal scenario would be I have my pure html/js front end posting a model as json and then have it turned into an actual model where I can validate it (through Sinatra or other framework) then make a decision based on the validation results.

Comment: Any information on validation? As all resources I find relating to model validation and ruby come back with ActiveRecord and RoR.

Comment: Yes, have a look at [ActiveModel](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at this gem:

- [json](http://flori.github.com/json/)

Then what you should be able to do is pass in the attributes for an object you would like to create as a hash of attributes converted to a json object:

```
{:attribute1 => "value1", :attribute2 => "value2"}.to_json
```

And on your Sinatra app, catch them and build the object from those attributes, and you can use Sinatra to validate as well:

```
def '/create_object' do
  content_type :json
  obj = Object.new(JSON.parse(params[:object]))

  if obj.save
    obj.to_json
  else
    error 400, user.errors.to_json
  end
end
```

Comment: Can I just have an instance call to_json? i.e I make an instance of a Person class then serialize it and send it down the wire? As some of my objects are quite complex.

Comment: I believe you should be able to do something like `Person.first.to_json`.  If you want to do more advanced serialization then you can pass in a serializer to the to_json method; take a look at this for more information about what you can do with serialization:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an ordinary case for an ORM. So you could for example use [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/). With that in your hands, you can simply send a form via HTTP to a specific route and do something like:

```
post '/create' do
  @post = Post.new(params[:your_form])
  if @post.save
    erb :a_template
  else
    erb :your_form
  end
end
```

Where params[:your_form] is a hash containing the contents of your form. No JSON needed at all. If the saving process fails (for validation reason or whatever), the model object `@post` will have errors, which you could process in a different view (`:your_form` for example).

Best Regards

Tobias

Comment: I was looking at DataMapper but my development environment is windows and the data adapters didnt seem to work, for the scope of this question I dont need an ORM i just want to be able to get a model and validate it, but in my real situation ORM would be one of the parts to it

Comment: If you only need the validation system, [ActiveModel](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) might be helpful.